# Using a query to pull data for today

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to pull the data from sheet 1, using the following formula:

```
=query(Sheet1!A1:V1850,"select I,A,D,E,F,H,R,S,L, M,O where I = 'TODAY()'")
```

So I do not have to enter todays date every time. How can it get it to pull that information?

[Here is the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jalkkbOeuifLD_jPHkmti_qu42ccn9F3hNHNrt08aWI/edit#gid=232048981).

Comment: The sheet does not seem to be public. Could you create an available, read-only version of it, and replace the link with that?

Comment: This is a good illustration of why one shouldn't rely on an external link for information germane to the question. A link is great for _support_, but you should endeavor to have all of the information needed in the question post itself. Even if the link worked _now_, there's no guarantee that it will continue to work in the future. We like questions and answers that are useful to more than just the original Asker.

Comment: @AlE. All true, except this specific question is clear without  a link to the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

To select the rows with today's date, the query string should be of the form

```
=query(..., "select ... where I = date '" & text(today(), "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'")
```

#### Explanation

1. In the [query language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#where), dates should be entered as `date '2015-02-09'`
2. Therefore, one has to format today's date as yyyy-mm-dd. This is what `text(today(), "yyyy-mm-dd")` does.
3. The ampersands concatenate strings, so we get `date '` followed by `2015-02-09` followed by `'`, achieving the  required format.

#### Remark

Putting 'TODAY()' within a double quoted string does not make it a formula: it's just the word TODAY(), treated as a part of that string. Formulas should be kept outside of strings, with their output concatenated to them as shown above.